# Extending Xcode 6 (ie, How to make [Mac]Ruby a first class Xcode citizen?)

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubymotion, macruby, xcode6

It seems to me that the introduction of Swift has some fantastic potential for Ruby and improving Ruby performance.  As a team, we're loving the ability to universally use Ruby at the moment.  For example, we have effectively replaced JavaScript with [Opal](http://opalrb.org) for our Ruby and Rails apps and are using RubyMotion for iOS ([and now soon Android](http://blog.rubymotion.com/post/87048665656/rubymotion-3-0-sneak-peek-android-support)) development.

**My question**: Are there any ways that we can bring Ruby into the status of first class citizen in Xcode so that we'll be able to take advantage of the Xcode 6 Playgrounds, get a ruby repl in Xcode's console, and perhaps take advantage of the other new offerings?

I am *HOPING* that we are not still screwed a la [this old request](http://openradar.appspot.com/8622025).

FYI, I have also posed this question to Apple via bugreport.apple.com in hopes to get some additional insight for extending Xcode from the other side of the fence.

Comment: Really don't know if this will be helpful, but I [made a petition here](http://www.change.org/petitions/craig-federighi-apple-please-allow-us-to-extend-the-diversity-of-xcode-6-to-other-languages) to see if we can knock on the proverbial door a bit. Not sure if I got Craig's email right, but hey, worth a shot... :)

Answer (score 2):

I also can't anticipate the internal decisions of Apple BUT there are some facts we can be sure of:

1. Apple is marketing Swift as THE future way to build iOS apps, there was no mention of adding additional Ruby support (or any other language) for XCode anywhere I've seen in WWDC 2014 announcements or elsewhere in the official Apple release notes, if I'm wrong, please link.
2. Laurent Sansonetti (as you probably know) was pretty much the MacRuby guy, he was the main developer on the project. Apple wasn't interested in really developing MacRuby further commercially and asked him to work on other Apple projects more (not to speak for him, this may be wrong but he mentioned this at Bubbleconf which I attended in 2012) http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/06/27/laurent-sansonetti-of-rubymotion-fame-to-speak-at-bubbleconf-2012/). He implied this was one of his reasons when he departed from Apple to found his company HipByte.
3. Apple has made no improvements to MacRuby support or to support Ruby for iOS, or XCode tooling for Ruby since 2012 when Laurent left. Correct me if I'm wrong.

If you're after a REPL or live-coding environment for RubyMotion, RubyMotion has a ticket for it in their bug tracker: http://hipbyte.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/RM-74. Please upvote it, even just hot reloading Teacup stylesheets would be a massive time-saver for us too.

Comment: I hear what you're saying. I fear you may be right, but I am hopeful that as a community we can at least express sufficient interest that they'll at the very least give us some hooks to get things done.  I was disappointed by a terse email that I got back from someone involved in the project that seemed to echo the sentiment about little interest in supporting Ruby, etc.  I tried to clarify that we don't need Apple to support it directly, but simply to give us some capacity to extend it if they're not already working on that.  We can probably hack it together, but it'd be nice to not have to.

Comment: So far I'm not real happy with Swift. Sure, it's nicer than obj-c, but there is nothing compelling enough to make one want to use it more than Ruby in terms of language appeal itself.

Comment: Mark, is that issue addressed with the upcoming 3.0 release: http://rubymotiondispatch.com/issues/2014/issue-30/: "Live code reloading"? - To answer that, YES, 3.0 implements that as per an answer I got back on a tweet just now.

Comment: @ylluminate yes, hope that's accurate, if so could be a real USP for RubyMotion.

Comment: @ylluminate As far as the language appeal of Swift vs Ruby that's mostly a subjective thing so I can't influence your perception of that but I do think Swift strikes a good balance between safety and aesthetics:

Comment: Well the Ruby vs Swift issue moves beyond subjective preference and perception when you can use it so ubiquitously as one can now using it to replace JS (Opal), do server work and dev client systems (OS X, iOS, Android). We have experienced serious benefits from this. You may also appreciate some potential here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15416